# Modelica - 'extends' with drop-down menu

Tags: inheritance, modelica

I think it is possible but I am not sure since I could not find any example. I would like to be able to choose the model I what to inherit directly in the parameter panel.

I can imagine two kinds of solutions:

```
extends model1 annotation(choices(choice(model1 "Ref"),choice(model2 "New")));
```

or

```
extends replaceable model1 annotation(choices(choice(redeclare model1 "Ref"),choice(redeclare model2 "New")));
```

---

Update: example to better explain what I would like to do: I would like to choose from the parameter panel of 'Final' which model to extend, among 'Data1' and 'Data2'.

```
package test

 partial model Data1
  parameter Real a=1;
  parameter Real b=2;
 end Data1;

 partial model Data2
  parameter Real a=1.1;
  parameter Real b=1.8;
 end Data1;

 model Final
  extends Data1; //(or Data2)
  Real y;
 equation
  y = a*time+b;
 end Final;

end test;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to have replaceable `extends`. You can have replaceable models that are `redeclared` within the model being extended but not the extended model itself. For example:

`extends model1(redeclare replaceable ...)`

You should be able to reorganize your structure so that it is not necessary to use a replaceable extends.

Comment: If I understand correctly, I should create an intermediate model (INT) just for declare a replaceable model (COMP) within it and than extend the INT model in the main model (MAIN) with a redeclare clause to being able to choose the COMP model to be used. It is not too complicate but neither straight-forward...and by the way I do not know if I could use a drop-down menu in this case...

Comment: I can't say for sure what the best way is since I don't really know what you're working on. What you suggest could be fine. Another option would be to just use replaceable models. Without more knowledge of your work I can't give you a better answer.

Comment: Just to confirm: replaceable extends is no longer supported in Modelica.

Comment: @HansOlsson. Thanks for confirming.